# How to fix the MBR without overwriting HD and without Recovery CD

Tags: windows-7, windows, mbr, partition-recovery

My volumes [c:/], [D: Removery] and [E: HP_Tools] have all turned into simple volumes due from trying to delete space from c:// and creating another partition to backup my files, so I can recover my computer to factory settings.

I did some research and I learned that the MBR files are corrupt. (Am I right?)

So how can I fix that but keep all my files? I don't have a recovery disc to my computer. I have that built in, but because of the drives turning into simple volume, I can't go to that by pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> (or whatever I have to press).

I have an HP Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit Laptop

Answer (score 2):

You can boot from some LiveCD Linux distribution and use TestDisk. It's an utility to inspect and fix hard drive problems and includes an options to either restore MBR from the backup or generate a new MBR.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a HP Laptop, it already has the maximum 4 partitions allowed, so you cannot create another partition with damaging one or more of the other 4, which you have discovered. So you cannot do what you want, use an external usb hard drive to store your data.

HP uses a custom Master Boot Record, using a recovery or regular Windows disc to fix the MBR will break this custom MBR, then your factory restore partition will not work.

HP has no easy method to repair the custom MBR other than do a full restore from the restore partition or HP recovery media. So back up your data and do a HP recovery.

I suggest you make your HP recovery media asap, label them appropriately and store in a safe place. 
http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01867124?jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0001

Also make this disc
http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02058933&DocLang=en&docLocale=en_US&jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0001

If you did not make your recovery media and cannot boot the PC:
You may be able to find HP recovery discs here since HP no longer offers them.

http://www.computersurgeons.com/Default.aspx

Also see this but W7 recovery media is no longer available from HP.
http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/bph07143

.

.

Comment: But theres only 3?

Comment: Where do you see this? Disk Management?

Answer (score 1):

You could borrow or download a copy of Windows Home Premium SP1 - just downloading the image is legal as far as I'm aware. Using this to boot into Windows Recovery console you would use the **fixmbr** command.

**Instructions** (*taken from* [*here*](http://www.ehow.com/how_4836283_repair-mbr-windows.html))

1. Insert the Windows 7 installation DVD and boot from the DVD drive. While in some older systems you may have to change boot order through system BIOS, most newer systems allow booting from DVD without changing boot order by simply clicking on any key when prompted to doing so.
2. Choose your default "Language", "Time", and "keyboard Input" on the first window and click next.
3. You're now presented with three choices.

   - Click on "Repair Your Computer" to gain access to the System Recovery window.
   - Now choose "Command Prompt" in order to run the desired utility which is called "bootsect.exe". Bootsect is located inside the boot folder so change your directory to boot.
   - Now run `bootsect /nt60 C:\` if you had Windows 7 initially installed in the C partition.

     - Alternatively, you can run `bootsect /nt60 SYS` or `bootsect /nt60 ALL` to repair the system partition or all partitions.
   - Eject the DVD, and restart the computer. Your computer should now boot Windows 7 again.

[Here](http://isohunt.com/torrents/Windows+7+Home+Premium) is a list of torrents taken from a popular site. This is provided to show how easy it is to find a download of what you're after. I would however recommend caution when downloading torrents.

Comment: According to the first comment on [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/404487/76872) you have to use the `/mbr` option as well because otherwise it won't fix MBR. So, you have to run `bootsect /nt60 C:\ /mbr` or one of the alternatives accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a live CD to boot in, ad then follow these steps -

1. Choose repair your computer
2. Select command prompt
3. Type in: bootrec.exe /fixmbr

This is it, your computer will now be able to boot normally.

Comment: This will work on a normal PC with regular windows, buit according to Moah's answer `HP uses a custom Master Boot Record, using a recovery or regular Windows disc to fix the MBR will break this custom MBR, then your factory restore partition will not work`. Is that incorrect for this spefific model?

Comment: well in that case, I think you should check this link and decide yourself - http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00476274 . I personally think it should work on your computer as well.

Comment: Not my computer. It would work on my PC since I use regular window disks (non-OEM). And EFI as well so I got a completely different setup. @Omnix seems to use the OEM setup though, or at least did in 2010. (question was recently edited to remove a deprecated tag, see meta for that).

Comment: @yashtheastral if that link is important you should cite it in an answer, not tell us to read it, in a comment